# How to use tcpdump to log only certain data in real time

Tags: linux, networking, monitoring, tcp, tcpdump

I'd like to monitor network interfaces, but only log things likes errors, collisions and dropped packets and send that to stdout. Can tcpdump be configured to do this?

Comment: If the packet was dropped, how is tcpdump going to see it?

Comment: Collisions don't really occur in modern switched networks and if they do then it's at a lower level than tcp dump.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm guessing what he really wants for that is to know when the TCP-layer network driver decides that a packet was probably dropped. So, the event he really wants to be informed of is when a packet is resent.

Comment: take a look at ifconfig and netstat -s

Comment: Its not just about dropped packets and/or how frequent collisions happen in today's modern networks. The fact is they can and do still happen, along with dropped packets and Tx/Rx errors. These things get logged, and I am looking for a way to capture these from whatever program tracks these events, then hopefully send that data to stdout.

Answer (score 1):

No.

You have a lot of filtering power on tcpdump, but what you're asking for can only be filtered when you've got more data. How can I know if a packet is a retransmission if I didn't log the original one? All the logic applied to a PCAP capture is done by e.g. Wireshark afterwards and taking the whole capture into account.

You may be better off logging traffic to chained files, let's say of 1GB in size and running some analysis tool like tshark from command line in a separate process that goes file by file. You can get some really nice output from there.

E.g. show retransmitted packets including source and destination IP:

```
tshark -Y "tcp.analysis.retransmission" -Tfields -e ip.src -e ip.dst
```

Answer (score 0):

```
netstat -ni
```

is your best friend for Tx/Rx errors (e.g. dropped packets at the NIC/driver/OS level). As they already said, collisions happen at a lower level and should be tracked on the switch I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You could use netstat coupled with the watch linux/unix command to see the errors in real time proactivly

e.g.

```
watch -n 2 netstat -in
```

And if you do want to log interface errors it'll be better to get the info from proc

e.g. using eth1

1. `cat /proc/net/dev | grep eth1 >> interface_errors_eth1`
2. Then put this as a cron job